# GraphQL Query Crashing On "If" Working on "Else If"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, graphql

I am trying to access a query from my frontend react page. When I call the query this

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

import { getBookQuery } from "../queries/queries";

export const BookDetails = (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getBookQuery, {
    skip: !props.bookId,
    variables: { id: props.bookId },
  });
  let content;
  if (loading) content = <p>Loading Detail...</p>;
  if (error) {
    content = <p>Error...</p>;
  } 
  if (!props.bookId) {
    content = <p>No book selected yet</p>;
  } else {
    console.log(data.book);
    const book = data;
  }
  return (
    <div id="hook-details">
    </div>
  );
```

When I run this code I see the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'book' of undefined**

To fix this error I changed the above code to use else if statements instead of just if statements, but I am failing to understand why this fixes the bug. Even when I throw log statements in each if block the same code seems to be called at the same time.

Working Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

import { getBookQuery } from "../queries/queries";

export const BookDetails = (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getBookQuery, {
    skip: !props.bookId,
    variables: { id: props.bookId },
  });
  let content;
  if (loading) content = <p>Loading Detail...</p>;
  else if (error) {
    content = <p>Error...</p>;
  }
  else if (!props.bookId) {
    content = <p>No book selected yet</p>;
  } else {
    console.log(data.book);
    const book = data;
  }

  return (
    <div id="hook-details">
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1st case

... when your component gets `bookId` prop following code works:

```
if (loading) content = <p>Loading Detail...</p>;
```

### and

```
} else {
  console.log(data.book);
  const book = data;
}
```

`data` is undefined at start then error appears.

### 2nd case

... **chained `if else` excludes the last fragment** (`console.log(data.book)`) **until data is loaded** - loading **OR** data access, no both (**AND**)

When `loading` gets `false` then `data` contains `book`, it can be safely logged out.

---

PS. It's safer to use 'early return':

```
if( !props.bookId ) return <NoBookSelectedMessage /> // or null to show nothing
if( loading ) return <Loading/>
if( error ) return <Error />
// 'data' must be defined here
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `data` value arrives **asynchronously** meanwhile you are expecting **synchronously**. Try using `useEffect` hook to catch changes on `data` after `useQuery` returned the value.

Like the following - by passing `data` into the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (data) {
      // your actions here
      console.log(data.book);
   }
}, [data]);
```

Suggested read: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

I hope this helps!